# Hyperledger composer rest server error grep

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am following the hyperledger composer tutorial in part 3 of the ibm docs
link: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-deploy-interact-extend-local-blockchain-network-with-hyperledger-composer/index.html
When I execute the composer-rest-server command which in essence starts the rest server,I get the following error and have no idea how to fix it.

```
    Discovering types from business network definition ...
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:666
                throw error;
                ^

Error: Connection is not in the READY state
    at ChannelEventHub._checkConnection (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:664:17)
    at ChannelEventHub.registerChaincodeEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/ChannelEventHub.js:825:8)
    at HLFConnection._registerForChaincodeEvents (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:279:44)
    at HLFConnection._checkCCListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:256:22)
    at Timeout.ccListenerHandle.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:381:35)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
```

This happens when I try to generate the rest server using composer-rest-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version: Use composer-rest-server v0.19.4 or later

Long version: grpc for node updated to 1.11 recently and introduced breaking changes. And this version was automatically picked up by the fabric node sdk which composer depends on. From v0.19.4 onwards we put a circumvention in to ensure that a compatible version of grpc was pulled in first that will fix this issue.